# How can I specify a custom collection/member route in Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Let's say that my server side API implements the following

```
GET /tournaments/1          # return a tournament data
POST /tournaments/1/seed    # seed the tournament
DELETE /tournaments/1/seed  # unseed the tournament
```

How should I implement this in my Ember Data model? Given the tournament looks something like this

```
App.Tournament = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string")
  ... bunch of stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to do this now, other than using jQuery.ajax and sideloading the results.

Answer (score 0):

Today you would create `adapters/tournament.js` and add something like:

```
export default Ember.RESTAdapter.extend({
  urlForCreateRecord(){
    return this._super(...arguments) + '/' + snapshot.id + '/seed';
  },
  urlForDeleteRecord(){
    return this._super(...arguments) + '/' + snapshot.id + '/seed';
  }
});
```